# IFTTT posting multiple times

Tags: wordpress, if-this-then-that, instagram

I recently connected Instagram to my WordPress blog. Today I noticed that pictures I like on Instagram are being posted 4 times on my blog. Has anybody encountered this error? Everything was working fine until today.

Comment: Tweet and ask them @IFTTT. As there isn't much details for us to debug, it's better if you ask them in person. If there is any bug, they will solve it.

Comment: I got this problem too by posting pictures through instagram to my wordpress blog via ifttt - could you get some feedback from ifttt?